# Fastest way to get mod 10 in C

Tags: c, performance, optimization, module

In my program I have a great presence of the operation `n % 10`. I know that the module operation can be done much faster when we have `n% m` where m is the power of 2, since it can be replaced by `n & (m-1 )`, however Is there any faster way to calculate modulus if the operand is 10?
In my case n is a uint8_t in some cases and in other cases n is an uint32_t.

Comment: This sounds much as a very premature optimization.If speaking of operation itself without context - trust the compiler, it will optimize it for you.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not always, for x86 it's more likely will generate _idiv_, while it's suboptimal.

Comment: @0andriy What would be more optimal? Again, given there is no context.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think bit operations with multiplication and addition or subtraction would give better results in some cases.

Comment: @0andriy That's what gcc x86-64 does [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/R8WWzn). Note: I don't have access to a x86-32 compiler.

Comment: @Blastfurnance, not bad, but have you checked other compilers? Btw, try to add _y = input / 10_ for the sake of experiment, I believe it will switch to _idiv_. However, there is maybe clever algorithms for constant divisors.

Comment: @0andriy Here's the [same code with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/xgQZFC). I do think the key here is constants known at compile time.

Comment: This is what I am saying. Trust the clever algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because most modern processors can do multiplication much, much faster than division, it is often possible to speed up division and modulus operations where the dividend is a known small constant by replacing the division with one or two multiplications and a few other fast operations (such as shift and addition).

To do so requires computing at compile-time some magic numbers dependent on the dividend; fortunately most modern compilers know how to do this so you don't need to do anything to take advantage.  Just let your compiler do the heavy lifting for you, as [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) suggests in [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61443373/1566221).

You can help the compiler by using unsigned types; for some dividends, signed division and modulus are harder to replace.

The basic outline of the optimisation of modulus looks like this:

If you had exact arithmetic, you could replace `x % p` with `p * ((x * (1/p)) % 1)`. For constant `p`, `1/p` can be precomputed at compile time. The `%1` operation simply consists of discarding the fraction part, which is just a right-shift. So that replaces a division with two multiplies, and if `p` only has a few bits set, the multiply by `p` might be further optimised into a few left-shifts.

We can do that computation with fixed-point arithmetic, taking advantage of the fact that most processors produce a double-sized result for integer multiplication. Since we don't care about the integer part of the inner multiplication and we know that the result of the outer multiplication must be less than `p`, we only need to reserve ceil(log2 p) bits for the integer part of the computation, leaving the rest of the bits for the fraction. And that might give us enough precision to correctly handle the possible range of values of `x`, particularly if `x` has a limited range (eg. `uint8_t` or even `uint16_t`). The key is finding a position of the fixed-point which minimises the error in representation of `1/p`.

For many small values of `p`, that works. For others, there is an alternative (but slower) solution which involves estimating `q = x/p` using multiplication by the inverse, and then computing `x - q * p`. If the estimate of `q` can be guaranteed to be either correct or off by one in a known direction, we only need to correct the final computation by conditionally adding or subtracting `p`; that can be accomplished without a branch on many modern CPUs. (The direction of the error is known because it will depend only on whether the approximation we chose for the inverse of the dividend was too small or too big.)

---

In the very specific case of `x % 10` where `x` is a `uint_8`, you might be able to do better than the above using a 256-byte lookup table. That would only be worthwhile if you were doing the modulus operation in a tight loop over a large number of values, and even then you'd want to profile carefully to verify that it is an improvement.

I doubt whether that's the best expenditure of your time; there are probably much more fruitful optimisation opportunities in your application.

Answer (score 0):

> however Is there any faster way to calculate modulus if the operand is 10?

With a good compiler, no.  The compiler would have already emitted good code.  You can explore different optimization settings with the compiler.

OTOH, if you know of some restrictions that the compiler cannot assume with `n % 10`, like values are always positive or of a sub-range, you might be able to out optimize the compiler.

Such [micro-optimisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/99445/94903) is usually not efficient use of programmer's time.

Comment: @rici  Re: {For the case where the argument is uint8_t a lookup table might be worthwhile.}  Perhaps.  Yet what appears to be tight code, may in fact take longer with a LUT  (cache concerns).  One could profile.   I stand by that it is not  efficient use of programmer's time.  Really perforce gains are far more often achieved with higher level optimization.

Comment: as it turns out, gcc can optimise better for unit8_x. Still, it's quite a few instructions which also occupy an important cache, while the LUT is only 256 bytes. Certainly only worthwhile thinking about in very limited circumstances (or out of curiosity).